# How to add Highcharts series automatically with a 2D-array?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to generate multi-series graphs like this one http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/. I have data stored in JavaScript 2D-arrays like this one:

```
[
[i, A, B, X],
[1, 1, 2, n],
[2, 1, 2, n],
[3, 1, 2, n],
[4, 1, 2, n]
]
```

In this case, "i" will be the x axis and the rest three columns would be different series with name 'A', 'B' and 'X'. But the number of series varies in each 2D-array. I have considered to parse the 2D-arrays into csv format and add series dynamically. But is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is to **convert** your data to any of the formats that Highcharts accepts:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kamil. But my question is how to let Highcharts generate the data series dynamically without manually defining the numbers and names of the series? For instance, can Highcharts automatically add a new series named 'X' in this example?  http://jsfiddle.net/mr79v45j/6/

Comment: What condition has to be satisfied to automatically generate a series and how Highcharts should determine the name and data for it?

Comment: The series names are in the first row, and the series data are in corresponding columns. But the numbers and names of the series can be different each time. Can Highcharts add those series automatically to a chart?

Comment: Highcharts accepts only the formats specified in the API/Docs - see my answer. You need to convert your data so that the will understand how to present it. You can use `addSeries` method to add series to already rendered chart: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart

Comment: What about data formats for column charts? Is that available somewhere as well?